# items-center only works with smaller font

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I'm using TailwindCSS to create a rounded button with a "+" in the middle. I'm using a flexbox to centre the plus character horizontally and vertically.

Vertical alignment starts going off if I increase the font size of the plus character too much. If I keep it small it works fine.

The current code is:

```
<div className="w-20 h-20 rounded-full bg-primary fixed bottom-10 right-10 cursor-pointer">
    <div className="flex h-full justify-center items-center text-secondary text-5xl p-0">+</div>
</div>
```

and renders into this:

[image: rendered plus button]